# Gradle plugins (findbugs, pmd, jdepend, checkstyle) not working

Tags: android, gradle, findbugs, pmd

I have the follow app **bulild.gradle** for my project. When I run the command gradle check no output is reported in the **app/build/** folder. I basically used the same code for a previous project and it seemed to work just fine.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "findbugs"
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: "jdepend"
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

findbugs {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "low"
}

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

jdepend{
    ignoreFailures = true
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.stylesheet resources.text.fromFile('config/xsl/checkstyle-custom.xsl')
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dat255.refugeeevent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile files ('libs/microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out gradle fury's quality plugin, works on android and non android projects https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury. We use it has something to force reports for the site plugin. It's largely based off of work of others with lots of tweaks to make it work correctly for both android and non android projects.

apply it
`allprojects  {
   apply from: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury/master/gradle/quality.gradle"
}`

and then you'll need the contents from here: https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury/tree/master/config cloned into your repo. Just the config folder, the rest of the stuff isn't needed.

finally, either call any gradle tasks that requires check. So any one of the following should do the trick

- `gradlew build`
- `gradlew check`
- `gradlew install` (if you're running the maven-support stuff from fury)

Comment: This solution is amazing

Comment: glad you like it. i hate that that much work was necessary in order for something simple to be usable

Comment: I could not agree more!

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration to you gradle.build file. Basically it does not find android repository and related details in your configuration.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use android studio and create a sample application to start android application. It will create default configuration which will save you from many unwanted problems

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it